# Induction on Fibonacci numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

For a homework problem, I need to prove $f_0f_1+f_1f_2+...+f_{2n-1}f_{2n}=f_{2n}^2$ for $n\geq1$ with induction. So far, using my basis step, I have $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} f_{2(k+1)-1}f_{2(k+1)}=$$ $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}f_{2k-1}f_{2k}\right)+f_{2k+1}f_{2k+2}=$$ $$f_{2k}^2+f_{2k+1}f_{2k+2}$$

However, I'm stuck here. I've tried breaking down the terms into their recursive terms and FOIL-ing/factoring, etc, and I can't seem to get to the end goal of $f_{2k+2}^2$. I might be missing something obvious... Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with indeces. After you use the induction hypothesis you should be left with $f_{2k}^2 + f_{2k}f_{2k+1} + f_{2k+1}f_{2k+2}$, and then it is easily done.

Comment: Ok. I see that that additional term fits into the pattern but that only every other term is given by $f_{2n-1}f_{2n}$ which is what I overlooked. Thank you, will try again.

Comment: @Kari did you manage to finish it yet?

Comment: Yes, after fixing the indexing I finished it very quickly!